Shadcn modified table - draggable component - error
I am an amateur programmer, I only started a few months ago. I am trying to create a custom component using shadcn table. I have been trying to do it myself and with the help of chatgpt but I am stuck on an error I can't resolve. I keep getting the error:
No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'children' does not exist in type 'Partial & Attributes'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(597, 14): The last overload is declared here.
(property) DOMAttributes.children?: React.ReactNode
"use client"
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";

// Define types for our props and state
type Column = {
  key: string;
  header: string;
};

type Row = Record<string, string | number>;

interface DraggableTableProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableElement> {
  columns: Column[];
  data: Row[];
}

const DraggableTable: React.FC<DraggableTableProps> = ({
  columns,
  data,
  className,
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [orderedColumns, setOrderedColumns] = useState<Column[]>(columns);
  const [draggedColumn, setDraggedColumn] = useState<Column | null>(null);
  const [dropTargetIndex, setDropTargetIndex] = useState<number | null>(null);

  const handleDragStart = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLTableCellElement>, column: Column) => {
    setDraggedColumn(column);
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLTableCellElement>, targetColumn: Column) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const targetIndex = orderedColumns.indexOf(targetColumn);
    if (draggedColumn && targetIndex !== -1 && targetIndex !== dropTargetIndex) {
      setDropTargetIndex(targetIndex);
    }
  };

  const handleDrop = () => {
    if (!draggedColumn || dropTargetIndex === null) return;

    const newOrderedColumns = orderedColumns.filter(col => col !== draggedColumn);
    newOrderedColumns.splice(dropTargetIndex, 0, draggedColumn);

    setOrderedColumns(newOrderedColumns);
    setDraggedColumn(null);
    setDropTargetIndex(null);
  };

  const clonedChildren = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child) && child.type === TableHeader) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        children: React.Children.map(child.props.children, (headerRow) => {
          if (React.isValidElement(headerRow) && headerRow.type === TableRow) {
            return React.cloneElement(headerRow, {
              children: orderedColumns.map((column, index) => (
                <TableHead
           a       key={column.key}
                  draggable
                  onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, column)}
                  onDragOver={(e) => handleDragOver(e, column)}
                  onDragLeave={() => setDropTargetIndex(null)}
                  onDrop={handleDrop}
                  className={cn(
                    "cursor-move",
                    draggedColumn === column && "bg-muted/25",
                    index === dropTargetIndex && "bg-muted/10"
                  )}
                >
                  {column.header}
                </TableHead>
              ))
            });
          }
          return headerRow;
        }),
      });
    }
    if (React.isValidElement(child) && child.type === TableBody) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        children: React.Children.map(child.props.children, (bodyRow) => {
          if (React.isValidElement(bodyRow) && bodyRow.type === TableRow) {
            return React.cloneElement(bodyRow, {
              children: orderedColumns.map((column) => (
                <TableCell key={column.key}>{data.find(row => row[column.key] === row[column.key])?.[column.key]}</TableCell>
              ))
            });
          }
          return bodyRow;
        }),
      });
    }
    return child;
  });

  return (
    <div className="relative w-full overflow-auto">
      <table
        className={cn("w-full caption-bottom text-sm", className)}
        {...props}
      >
        {clonedChildren}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

interface TableHeaderProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableSectionElement> {
  columns: Column[];
  data: Row[];
  className?: string; // Optional string
  children?: React.ReactNode; // Could be a string or other elements
  // ...props
}
interface DraggableTableProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableElement> {
  columns: Column[];
  data: Row[];
  className?: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode; // Could be a string or other elements
  // ...props
}

const TableHeader = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLTableSectionElement,
  TableHeaderProps
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <thead ref={ref} className={cn("[&_tr]:border-b", className)} {...props} />
));
TableHeader.displayName = "TableHeader";

interface TableBodyProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableSectionElement> {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const TableBody = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLTableSectionElement,
  TableBodyProps
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <tbody
    ref={ref}
    className={cn("[&_tr:last-child]:border-0", className)}
    {...props}
  />
));
TableBody.displayName = "TableBody";

const TableRow = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLTableRowElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableRowElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <tr
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      "border-b transition-colors hover:bg-muted/50 data-[state=selected]:bg-muted",
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  />
));
TableRow.displayName = "TableRow";

const TableHead = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLTableCellElement,
  React.ThHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableCellElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <th
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      "h-12 px-4 text-left align-middle font-medium text-muted-foreground [&:has([role=checkbox])]:pr-0",
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  />
));
TableHead.displayName = "TableHead";

const TableCell = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLTableCellElement,
  React.TdHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableCellElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <td
    ref={ref}
    className={cn("p-4 align-middle [&:has([role=checkbox])]:pr-0", className)}
    {...props}
  />
));
TableCell.displayName = "TableCell";

const TableCaption = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLTableCaptionElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableCaptionElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <caption
    ref={ref}
    className={cn("mt-4 text-sm text-muted-foreground", className)}
    {...props}
  />
));
TableCaption.displayName = "TableCaption";

export {
  DraggableTable as Table,
  TableHeader,
  TableBody,
  TableRow,
  TableHead,
  TableCell,
  TableCaption,
};

Defining the props for DraggableTable but it hasn't helped. I used Ai to check it but it can't figure it out either.
